# How to imitate autocomplete search with Redis ZRANGEBYLEX?

Tags: autocomplete, redis

I'm trying to make a simple autocomplete system much like the demo here: http://autocomplete.redis.io/ but for some reason I can't get the `ZRANGEBYLEX` to return the right results. Here's what I'm doing on the Redis CLI:

```
> zadd autocomplete 0 one 0 two 0 three 0 four 0 five 0 six 0 seven 0 eight 0 nine 0 ten 0 eleven 0 twelve 0 thirteen 0 fourteen 0 fifteen
```

My set looks good:

```
> zrangebylex autocomplete - +
1) "eight"
2) "eleven"
3) "fifteen"
4) "five"
5) "four"
6) "fourteen"
7) "nine"
8) "one"
9) "seven"
10) "six"
11) "ten"
12) "thirteen"
13) "three"
14) "twelve"
15) "two"
```

And if I use `ZRANGEBYLEX` like this the result makes sense:

```
zrangebylex autocomplete [e [eight
1) "eight"
```

But if I want to get all items in the set that *start* with an "e" I try this (which is very similar to what the autocomplete demo shows) but it doesn't return the right results:

```
> zrangebylex autocomplete [e [e(0xff)
(empty list or set)
```

What must one use as params to the `ZRANGEBYLEX` command in order for it to match any strings beginning with "e" and anything else afterwards?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrangebylex autocomplete [e "[e\xff"
1) "eight"
2) "eleven"
```

**Edit**: As noted by Itamar Haber in his comment below, when using a code client, you do **not** need quotes.

Comment: It sure does. What exactly do the quotes do?

Comment: Apparently force redis-cli to treat the value as a literal string. When using a regular client from code, the quotes are not needed though.

Comment: @ItamarHaber what's the meaning of `\xff`? i don't understand

Comment: '\' is an escape character, 'x' denotes hexadecimal character representation and 'ff' is 255 in base 16. Hence, '\xff' is the largest (lexicographically-wise) character.

Comment: Something that may not be readily apparent - if you simply used [ez instead of [e\xff, you wouldn't be able to include strings with apostrophes like e'vret in your results.